# Alternative to type checking for method selection

Tags: c#, oop

I have a tree of classes that describe interactive items, which in turn can be applied one onto another. When there's an attempt to do so, the base class checks on the type of the action target and chooses an appropriate handler method, which is overridden in descendants according to their purpose.

```
public abstract class BasicItem
{
    public void Interact(BasicItem pair)
    {
        if(pair is Tool tool)
            HandleInteractionWithTool(tool);
        else if (pair is Container container)
            HandleInteractionWithContainer(container);
        else if(pair is Book book)
            HandleInteractionWithBook(book);
    }

    protected virtual void HandleInteractionWithTool(Tool tool) { }
    protected virtual void HandleInteractionWithContainer(Container container) {}
    protected virtual void HandleInteractionWithBook(Book book) {}
}

public class Tool: BasicItem
{
    protected override void HandleInteractionWithContainer(Container container) 
    {
    //...
    }
}
```

I suppose this is what can described as runtime type resolution.
I'm not a performance hypochondriac, and casting with **is** is not an issue.
What is an issue is that I already have about 15 classes among those "HandleInteractionWith..." methods, and the list is going to grow. It feels wrong, it looks wrong, and I'm ashamed of this "architecture".

Is there a better approach? Something tells me there's a pattern for this, and it involved generic methods.

The context is a Unity project, but I don't think it's very important.

Cheers.

Comment: The literal answer to your question is a C# syntax matter.  But could it be you're completely missing the point of Unity?  Unity is an ECS system and is not even vaguely related to OO engineering.  Unity is like photoshop. You have a collection of items.  So in photoshop you have "a plane" and on it are "lines".  In Unity you have "a space" and in it are "GameObjects".  GameObjects can have "Components" on them. If you want a game object to have some qualities/abilities (let's say, "fly", "run", "vibrate") you add components (likelly fly.cs, run.cs and vibrate.cs) to that game object.

Comment: @Fattie this is `c#` though and thereby it **IS** OO engineering though I know from the past that you strictly try to deny that ^^ But as you can see this question isn't even Unity related at all since `BasicItem` isn't inheriting any Unity specific type at all .. it is as simply base class ....

Comment: This is called double dispatch (a correct method needs to be picked based on the types of two objects rather than just one), and there are multiple approaches for achieving it in single-dispatch languages like C#, including but not limited to the visitor pattern, dictionaries of delegates and `dynamic`. None of these are particularly "clean" because you are after all trying to do something the language doesn't support as a first-class citizen; as long as clients (in this case derived classes) aren't required to spend more effort than necessary you can afford some awkwardness in the internals.

Comment: I recall implementing the Visitor pattern before, but somehow it didn't come to mind this time. I will refresh my memory of it, thank you.
I briefly considered 'dynamic' as an alternative, but it is indeed dirtier architecture-wise. And having a collection of delegates effectively just moves my so hated list of handler methods to a different place.

Comment: you can atleast replace the `if-else` by a `switch-case` using e.g. `switch(pair) { case Tool tool: /*...*/ break; }`

Comment: why not rather use an overload and directly do e.g. `public virtual void Interact(Tool pair){}`, `public virtual void Interact(Book pair){ }`, `public virtual void Interact(Container pair){ }` .. etc ?

Comment: @derHugo, well, because what arrives as an argument is another BasicItem, it won't resolve which overload to use, if any.

Comment: hi @derHugo , certainly, if you use C# to write Components, for unity game objects, then C# itself is OO - anywhere C# is used, C# is indeed OO !  if you use machine code to write the components, OO is not involved in machine code.  but they're just components.  unity, as such, as no relationship to OO or, really, much to do with programming!  As I said at the start, "The literal answer to your question is a C# syntax matter" but as an observation, this is just "not even vaguely" how you do such a common thing in Unity. Purely FWIW.

Comment: note that indeed the OP is trying to make a *component* which is a "thing".  Say in a unity project you will have "things" such as "tanks", "rocks" and "clouds".  Then, you have in Unity "abilities" such as "can fly", "jumps", "walks" or the like.   **The first category are game objects.  The second category are components.**  Whenever you see someone who has a component name like "gun" or "cloud" - you know instantly they are generally likely misguided.  a "gun" or "cloud" or a "tool" is a prefab (ie, a game object)...

Comment: if U have three tools (hammer, saw, pliers) those are three prefabs (or perhaps one prefab with a toggle type of arrangement to swap out mesh, components, whatever).  whatever "abilities" you want those things to have (deal damage, animate, make hammering sound effects, be magnetic etc) would be components.  {Sure, you might have a script named "Dog" that goes on the dog prefab, to wrangle it and identify it, but you get the spirit of what I mean in the preceeding comment)  So!

Comment: @PhilMcLaren So for every new subtype you add, all existing needs to treat it differently in its own special way? This code looks very weird to me that when you claim you want a `BasicItem`, you shouldn't expect its concrete type. OOP would suggest you programming towards abstraction, not implmentation.